# Query DSL - generate correct query

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, querydsl, spring-mongodb

I want to create this query:

```
{"userType":"USER","$and":[{"$or":[{"firstName":{"$regularExpression":{"pattern":".*\\QJohn\\E.*","options":""}}},{"lastName":{"$regularExpression":{"pattern":".*\\QJohn\\E.*","options":""}}},{"middleName":{"$regularExpression":{"pattern":".*\\QJohn\\E.*","options":""}}}]},{"$or":[{"firstName":{"$regularExpression":{"pattern":".*\\QDoe\\E.*","options":""}}},{"lastName":{"$regularExpression":{"pattern":".*\\QDoe\\E.*","options":""}}},{"middleName":{"$regularExpression":{"pattern":".*\\QDoe\\E.*","options":""}}}]}]}
```

But I get this query:

```
{"$and":[{"userType":"USER","$or":[{"firstName":{"$regularExpression":{"pattern":".*\\QJohn\\E.*","options":""}}},{"lastName":{"$regularExpression":{"pattern":".*\\QJohn\\E.*","options":""}}},{"middleName":{"$regularExpression":{"pattern":".*\\QJohn\\E.*","options":""}}}]},{"$or":[{"firstName":{"$regularExpression":{"pattern":".*\\QDoe\\E.*","options":""}}},{"lastName":{"$regularExpression":{"pattern":".*\\QDoe\\E.*","options":""}}},{"middleName":{"$regularExpression":{"pattern":".*\\QDoe\\E.*","options":""}}}]}]}
```

What wrong do I do? It is my **queryDSL** builder:

```
    QUser user = QUser.user;
    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder(user.userType.eq(UserType.USER));

    BooleanExpression e1 = Expressions.anyOf(
            user.firstName.contains("John"),
            user.lastName.contains("John"),
            user.middleName.contains("John"));

    BooleanExpression e2 = Expressions.anyOf(
            user.firstName.contains("Doe"),
            user.lastName.contains("Doe"),
            user.middleName.contains("Doe"));

    BooleanExpression e3 = Expressions.allOf(e1, e2);

    builder.and(e3);
```

This builder generates this pseudocode(I saw in debbuger):

```
user.userType = USER 
&& (contains(user.firstName,John) || contains(user.lastName,John) || contains(user.middleName,John)) 
&& (contains(user.firstName,Doe) || contains(user.lastName,Doe) || contains(user.middleName,Doe))
```

I need to get a query like a query in my first example.

**EDITED**:

I created the correct query with criteria. Can someone create the same with queryDSL?

```
    Query query = new Query();

    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("userType").is(UserType.USER);

    Criteria criteria1 = new Criteria();
    criteria1.orOperator(
            Criteria.where("firstName").is("John"),
            Criteria.where("lastName").is("John"),
            Criteria.where("middleName").is("John"));

    Criteria criteria2 = new Criteria();

    criteria2.orOperator(
            Criteria.where("firstName").is("Doe"),
            Criteria.where("lastName").is("Doe"),
            Criteria.where("middleName").is("Doe"));

    criteria.andOperator(criteria1, criteria2);

    query.addCriteria(criteria);
```

Comment: You're affected by a bug in the MongoDB serializer.This hopefully will be fixed in the next version of QueryDSL.

Comment: @Jan-Willem Gmelig Meyling  Are you sure? I spent a lot of time on that. If you are sure I will use criteria in this case. Can you share a link with this bug?

Comment: See https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2638 and https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/2689#discussion_r516029138

Comment: The last comment provides a fix, but in a different module. The fix still needs to be applied to the MongodbSerialzer in the querydsl-mongodb module.